# Taking screenshot and setting it again as UIImageView make it smaller size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, screenshot

I am working on a project where I need to take the screenshot at particular time interval programmatically of a UIImageView and set that image back to that UIImageView. But when I do this, the UIImageview comes with smaller size image then the previous one. Below is the code how I am taking the screenshot.

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

and I set it as

```
theImageView.image=[self screenshot];
```

Why the image comes with smaller size everytime? And it gets smaller and smaller and smaller.

Please share the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: screenshot of imageview or window?

Comment: Why are you taking this  as negative?? "-[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x"

Comment: @sanchitsingh - you wrote all the code just for a screenshot. You want to take screenshot of whole imageView or something else ?

Comment: I want to take the screenshot of wholescreen and then set the resulted image back to the UIImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code helped me for taking screen shot in a better manner

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return capturedImage;
}
```